# Using for loop in R: compute the column means

Tags: r, for-loop

I tried to do the exercise "compute the mean of every column in mtcars". I know the easiest way is to use `colmeans()`

```
colMeans(mtcars)
```

but I still want to figure out the way by using for loop. Here is my code, but not working. I have tried many times, but cant find out the error (quite frustrating...).
Your reply will be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

```
for (i in c(1:11)) {   #mtcars has 11 columns
    y1<-mean(mtcars[,i])
    y2<-c(y1,y2)
}
y2
```

Kate

---

Thank you so much for replies.
Following the online comments, I updated the code as follows:

```
y2<-numeric()
 for (i in seq_along(mtcars)) {
 y1<-mean(mtcars[,i])
 y2<-c(y1,y2)
}
y2
 [1]   2.812500   3.687500   0.406250   0.437500  17.848750   3.217250
 [7]   3.596563 146.687500 230.721875   6.187500  20.090625
```

If using colMeans()...

```
colMeans(mtcars)
    mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec 
 20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750 
    vs         am       gear       carb 
 0.437500   0.406250   3.687500   2.812500
```

It is quite interesting to see the list is totally reverse (compared to the code in the first part). Then I found out the issue in y2<-c(y1,y2)
if I change original y2<-c(y1,y2) into...

```
y2<-c(y2,y1)
```

The final version....

```
y2<-numeric()
 for (i in seq_along(mtcars)) {
 y1<-mean(mtcars[,i])
 y2<-c(y2,y1)
}
y2
[1]  20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250
[7]  17.848750   0.437500   0.406250   3.687500   2.812500
```

This result finally matched with the results in colMeans()!!

Thank you all once again for the help!!

Kate

Comment: `sapply(mtcars, mean)` will do it

Comment: You have not initialized `y2`.

Comment: or `out <- c(); for (col in names(mtcars)) {out[[col]] <- mean(mtcars[[col]])}; out`

Comment: You have to initialize `y2` before doing the loop: `y2 <- numeric()`

Comment: Also try `seq_along(mtcars)` instead of `c(1:11)` it's better.

Comment: Dear all, thank you for reply. I tried your comments and updated the code as follows but the result is still not as expected.

Comment: @PengKate Please update your question with the code you've tried.

Comment: @markus, I posted the code as above and explain the problem I encountered at first and how it is solved based on the previous comments.

Comment: Thank you all for the prompt help!! I learned a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a standard way to do it with a loop:

```
# Extract the number of columns
ncols <- length(mtcars)
# Initialize your mean vector (this will make the loop run much faster)
column_means <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = ncols)
# Now loop through each column
for (i in 1:ncols) {   
  column_means[i] <- mean(mtcars[[i]])
}
# Why not turn our mean vector into a named vector so we can better make sense 
# of the numbers
names(column_means) <- names(mtcars)
column_means

       mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec         vs         am       gear 
 20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750   0.437500   0.406250   3.687500 
      carb 
  2.812500
```

**But how to make the original code work?**

```
y2 <- NULL
for (i in c(1:11)) {   #mtcars has 11 columns
    y1<-mean(mtcars[,i])
    y2<-c(y2, y1)
}
```